# "Can't use string as a hash ref" hash of hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash

i seem to got into trouble handling hash of hash of hashes.
My data structure is like this:

```
$atomsArray{$number}{$serial} = {
    atom => $atom,
    x => $x,
    y => $y,
    z => $z
};
```

and i get into this trouble while iterating through atoms

```
for my $number(sort keys %atomsArray){
    for my $serial(sort keys %{$atomsArray{$number}}){
       #cannot iterate through x,y,z
    }
}
```

Although, i would want to get x,y,z without iterating through $serial,
and it is important to have hash in a hash, because it differs between which atoms i have to calculate atoms.

Comment: It's not whether it's good or not, i need a way to iterate through third level hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am such a stupid person, i couldn't get simple iteration.
The answer how to iterate hash of hash of hashes is :

```
for my $number(sort keys %atomsArray){
   for my $serial(sort keys %{$atomsArray{$number}}){
      print $atomsArray{$number}{$serial}{'x'};
   }
}
```